# assign data from table with different id to labels using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hy all.I want to assign data from a table to some labels.For example: If I have 3 records with ID=1,ID=2 and ID=3 I want this records to be assigned to 3 different labels.so label1=data with ID=1, label2=data with ID=2 and so on.How can I achieve that?

Comment: Also, when you say records it means a table row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested, may have syntax problem, but you get the idea.

```
string qry="select Column1,Column2,Column3 from YourSchema.YourTable";
using (SQLConnection myConnection=new SQLConnection(Web.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    using(SQLCommand myCommand=new SQLCommand(qry,myConnection))
    {
        try 
        {
             myConnection.Open(); 
             using(SQLDataReader myReader= myCommand.ExecuteReader())
             {
                 if(myReader.HasRows)
                 {
                      while(myReader.Read())
                      {
                         Label1.Text= myReader[0].ToString();
                         Label2.Text= myReader[1].ToString();
                         Label3.Text= myReader[2].ToString();
                      }
                 }
             }
        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
             // Log exception
             throw ex;
        }  
        finally
        {
            if(myConnection!=null)
                myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't bring anything..I don't get any error but nothing is display

Comment: You will not get an error as exception is thrown. Please replace the 'qry' sample query with your own database query. It is just a sample to get you started.